# How to include symlinks and the linked file in a python wheel using Poetry?

Tags: python-3.x, python-poetry

I have a python package that I want to include some specific files from a submodule without including the entire package, so the structure looks like:

```
foo_project
 |
 +-- submodule_files
     +-- bar.json
     +-- other_stuff
 +-- foo
     +-- __init__.py
     +-- foo.py
     +-- <symlink to bar.json>
```

The poetry toml file has

```
packages = [
    { include = "foo" }
]
```

When the wheel is created using `poetry build`, the linked files are copied, but not the links themselves

```
 foo_wheel
 |
 +-- submodule_files
     +-- bar.json
 +-- foo
     +-- __init__.py
     +-- foo.py
```

(left out info directory in wheel for brevity)

Therefore once installed, the python package is missing the extra files

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?