# Poetry include additional data files in wheel

Tags: python, python-poetry, python-wheel

I have a simple python package, let's call it `my_package`.

Its files are located in `src/python/my_package`.
In addition, there is a `data` folder in the repository root, which should be included in the resulting python wheel within the `my_package`.

```
.
├── src
    └── python
        └── my_package
├── data
    └── stuff.json
├── pyproject.toml
```

I did not find any way to configure poetry that it includes the additional `data` folder in the correct way.

Here is my `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-package"
version = "2.10.0" 

packages = [
    { include = "my_package", from = "src/python" }
]

# This does not work! It puts the `data` folder into site-packages/data instead of site-packages/my_package/data
include = [
    { path = "data", format = ["sdist", "wheel"] }
]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

I also found the following solution, using a pre-build script:
https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5539#issuecomment-1126818974

Problem: it changes the wheel that it is not pure anymore, but depends on CPython.

Also tried with symlink, but that does not work: [How to include symlinks and the linked file in a python wheel using Poetry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65670606/how-to-include-symlinks-and-the-linked-file-in-a-python-wheel-using-poetry)

**Question:
What is the correct way to include additional resource files in a python wheel using poetry?**

Comment: Your data files must be part of the importable package. Can't you move the `data` directory to `src/python/my_package/data`? This would make everything much easier.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an option, since the data folder is also ised by some other scripts within the repo, where it cannot be moved.

Comment: ***A.*** I think I know how I would solve this with *setuptools*, but I can not seem to find a straightforward solution with Poetry. Are you bound to Poetry? Would you consider changing to *setuptools* for this? -- ***B.*** I gave it a try to solve this with Poetry's `build.py` but hit the same wheel tag issue, asked the maintainers and there is no solution to fix wheel tags from `build.py`. I think you can use the `wheel` tool to fix the wheel tags afterwards -- ***C.*** Maybe you could have a pre-build step (maybe a shell script) to copy `data` to `src/python/my_package/data`.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry-core/pull/227 -- On the other hand I tried using the `wheel` tool to fix the tags, and it seems to work. But this means the project needs a post-build step (in the CI/CD for example). And it seems it would be better to have a pre-build step instead that copies the `data` directory to the right location, because then there is no need for `build.py` at all.

Comment: Hatch could probably do it easily as well: https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/build/#rewriting-paths